# Is it possible to display date in a label other than string format?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I'm new to iphone developing. In my application i assigned date value to a label, but the label value did not change when the application gets executed.

```
NSDate *dateTemp = [[NSDate alloc] init];

cell.newlabel.text=dateTemp;
```

Comment: place your coding adding to the label, and which event you are calling it from

Comment: Yeah, you need to describe your problem MUCH better.  A few lines of the code you're executing, etc.

Comment: @aswin can you post some code for better understand ?

Comment: NSDate *dateTemp = [[NSDate alloc] init];  cell.newlabel.text=dateTemp;

Comment: Yep, you need to use NSDateFormatter.  And before you ask questions about that search here and with Google -- just about every question you could have about NSDateFormatter has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only put NSString into a UILabel.  To display an NSDate in a UILabel you have to convert it to NSString first.  For that you'll need to learn about NSDateFormatter.